# Enviar archivos a Strapi POST

Tags: reactjs, post, http, strapi

tengo un problema, estoy haciendo mi aplicación en react y Strapi, he creado mi token para autorizar a mi aplicación y he podido traer los datos de Strapi GET,
pero ahora quiero hacer un POST y no he podido, ya que muestra un error que no se como resolver, ya intente de todo.
El error en consola de strapi es el siguiente:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of 'parseBody(...)' as it is undefined.

El error de mi funcion es este:

```
    data
: 
null
error
: 
{status: 500, name: "InternalServerError", message: "Internal Server Error"}
message
: 
"Internal Server Error"
name
: 
"InternalServerError"
status
: 
500
```

mi funcion es la siguiente:

```
    export const createBlog = async (data) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('title', data.title);
        formData.append('author', data.author);
        formData.append('image_content', data.image_content);
        formData.append('miniature', data.miniature);
        formData.append('release', data.release);
        formData.append('text_content', data.text_content);
        formData.append('published', data.published);
    const url = import.meta.env.VITE_STRAPPI_URL + '/api/travel-blogs';
    console.log('createBlog', data);
    console.log('createBlog', url);
    console.log('createBlog', formData);
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(url, formData, { headers });
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating blog:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

El objeto con los datos se pinta correctamente, estoy usando un reducer para capturar los datos y si los captura, pero no puede hacer correctamente el POST, alguna idea que puede ser? gracias